# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  8         44
Users destroyed                                  77          0
Users deleted                                     7          0
Users contacted                                  12          0
User suspensions lifted early                     2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            87      1,054
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               21        919
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        118        835
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               56        503
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               147      1,101
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               21      1,066
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          2
Tag synonyms created                              0          1
Questions unprotected                            18         41
Questions reopened                               18        146
Questions protected                               0         60
Questions migrated                                0          1
Questions flagged⁴                               17        870
Questions closed                                136        632
Question flags handled⁴                         351        536
Posts unlocked                                    3          2
Posts undeleted                                  33        947
Posts locked                                      4        125
Posts deleted⁵                                  258      2,884
Posts bumped                                      0         32
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               46          0
Comments flagged                                  9      4,138
Comments deleted⁶                             6,634     12,839
Comment flags handled                         1,287      2,860
Bounties canceled                                 8          0
Answers flagged                                  49        854
Answer flags handled                            558        345
All comments on a post moved to chat             42          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: What about moderation (flagging, moving, editing after time limit, deleting after time limit, suspending users, granting access to low-rep users, super-pinging, etc.) in chat rooms associated with PPCG?

Comment: Grouping non-moderator users with user #-1 seems confounding to me. For example, because of PPCG pecularities (we encourage unusually many answers per question), I suspect most Protect actions are by #-1 and most Unprotect actions are other users reverting these on sight (I know I do).

Comment: Number of site design: 0